# How to use CHECK constraint to restrict non-numeric varchar2 (only alphabets)?

Tags: sql, check-constraint

I have a column NAME
It must contain only characters and not numbers
How do I use CHECK condition:

```
CHECK(NAME NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%')
```

or any other method...

edit: Oracle database is used.

Comment: LIKE (at least in the SQL Standard) does not support regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't state your DBMS so I'm assuming PostgreSQL

```
CHECK(name ~ '^[^0-9]*$')
```

Answer (score 3):

[Double negative](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8744173/27535) Should be standard (not MySQL though) because it uses LIKE:

```
CHECK(NAME NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z]%')
```

Comment: That's **not** standard SQL, as the standard does not support regular expressions for LIKE. Which DBMS does support this kind of syntax?

Comment: SQL server, sybase. It isn't refectory either

Comment: what does "*refectory*" mean? (I'm not a native speaker)

Comment: He he. Spell check on my phone... regex I mean