# Check if string consists of letters or numbers only in Transact-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I check if a string consists of letters or numbers ONLY in Transact-SQL?

Here the string has datatype `nchar`, 'letters' specifically refer to latin characters. Database environment is Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

Example for desired result:

```
C172E returns True
412?A returns False  //'?' is neither a letter nor a number
```

I've done some searching but only found the built-in `ISNUMERIC()` function, which is for numbers only.

Is there a Transact-SQL solution for this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this similar question about [obtaining only fields with alphanumeric data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744173/using-select-to-obtain-only-fields-with-alphanumeric-data-and-certain-punctuati?answertab=active#tab-top)

You can do the following:

`FIELD NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'`

Comment: Thanks, after some testing I found out that this works for `nvarchar` type. There could be spaces in `nchar` string which needs to be considered, otherwise it would always return false.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `not like`:

```
(case when str not like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%' then 1 else 0 end) as isalnum_flag
```

This is saying that the string has no non-alphanumberic characters.

Comment: Thanks, this really helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at using [Regex](https://www.sqlshack.com/t-sql-regex-commands-in-sql-server/) to do this. [a-zA-Z] is char, [0-9] is numeric, [a-zA-Z0-9] is both. You mention having to add in spaces? \s is white space characters (this could be more than just the fields.

[This one](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9106/using-regular-expressions-with-tsql-from-beginner-to-advanced/) is a bit more involved (more depth).